# C++ Have function on compile time calculate global variables

Tags: c++, function, global, constexpr, compile-time

I have 3 global variables that I wish to compute on compile time without needing to get the results first and assign the globals manually.

The way I currently have it set up is there is a function named Init() that simply computes the 3 variables, and this Init() function is called near the top of Main.
What I have tried doing is adding constexpr to the front of the function but printing the values before the call to Init() just has the variables as 0.

What would be the best way, if any at all, to have the function Init() in the following code ran at compile time and have the 3 globals already calculated as the program begins.

Example Code:

```
static const int length = 8;
static const int seed = 40;

long long key1, key2, key3; // I want these to be calculated at compile-time instead of run-time if possible

void Init() {
    key1 = pow(seed, length);
    key2 = key1 * seed;
    key3  = key2 * seed;
}

...
void main(int argc,char * argv[]) {
    Init();
    ...
}
```

Edit:

I did something like following, and appears to have worked as I can print the values out at the top of main:
Is there anything I can do to improve or shorten the amount of code for this to work?

```
constexpr long long calcKey1() {
    long long key1 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++)
        key1 *= seed;

    return key1;
}

constexpr long long calcKey2(const long long key1) {
    return key1* seed;
}

constexpr long long calcKey3(const long long key2) {
    return key2 * seed;
}

constexpr long long key1 = calcKey1();
constexpr long long key2 = calcKey2(key1);
constexpr long long key3 = calcKey3(key2);
```

Comment: The code presented not being *real* code notwithstanding, *"...the following code ran at compile time..."* - code doesn't run at compile-time; it is *built* at compile-time. Your post begs the question, what problem are you actually trying to solve? Because, this has all he aroma of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if ever there was one.

Comment: It is the 1st sentence of my post, "I have 3 global variables that I wish to compute on compile time"
I wish those 3 variables to have already been calculated before the program starts if possible.

Comment: @TJ8 You need to have a `constexpr` function for each of these variables returning an appropriate value. Also you need these variables being marked as `constexpr` that you can reuse these in compile time calculations. And last but not least, you'll need to provide a `constexpr` version of `pow()` (such might be possible with a recursive template).

Comment: I made an edit to my original post which includes your suggestions and appears to work. Is this the most optimal way or can it be shortened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to used `constexpr`. But it's not always going to work.

Typically `std::pow` is not `constexpr` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

If you really want to have compile-time computations, you need to implement these missing functions as `constexpr` yourself. Indeed, the standard library is generally not `constexpr`, so it will still do stuff at runtime. Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRDNPwXDVp0&frags=pl%2Cwn for more information on what is in store for the future.